# Nativescript - get label id at index

Tags: nativescript

I actually didn´t know how to describe the title of this question in a better way, but i will try to explain myself the best i can:

I´m making an app where the users will be able to order food and it will be delivered at home, so at certain point i have a menu list and in this list there are groups of food(group of salmon, group of pastas ect...it´s a sushi app).

So let´s say i have selected salmon, i will have a listview that looks like this:

[image]

Well, as you can see there´s a counter there and it´s function i think it´s obvious and the code i´m using for the incremention of the food is below:

```
<GridLayout row="2" rowSpan="2" col="2" rows="*" columns="40,25,40" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="right" marginRight="10">
                    <Label row="0" col="0" text="+" tap="onTapPlus" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" style="color:black;font-family: 'Allerta Stencil', sans-serif;font-size:20px;"></Label>
                    <Label id="nrItemsTakeAway" row="0" col="1" text="0" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" style="color:black;font-family: 'Allerta Stencil', sans-serif;font-size:20px;"></Label>
                    <Label row="0" col="2" text="-" tap="onTapMinus" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" style="color:black;font-family: 'Allerta Stencil', sans-serif;font-size:20px;"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

I have a tap event for the plus button, and i have a tap event for the minus button, and both will influence the label with the id nrItemsTakeAway...but has you already guessed the id has to be unique to each record in the listview...**how will i diferenciate this?**

Ps: i´m using javascript

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using NativeScript Core flavour for development, you should use Observable to bind your data.

For example,

**ViewModel**

```
import { Observable, fromObject } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable';
import { ObservableArray } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable-array';

export class HomeViewModel extends Observable {
    items: ObservableArray<Observable> = new ObservableArray([
        fromObject({ name: "Item 1", count: 1 }),
        fromObject({ name: "Item 2", count: 1 }),
        fromObject({ name: "Item 3", count: 1 }),
        fromObject({ name: "Item 4", count: 1 }),
    ]);

    onPlusTap(args) {
        args.object.bindingContext.count += 1;
    }

    onMinusTap(args) {
        args.object.bindingContext.count -= 1;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<ListView class="list-group" items="{{ items }}">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
                <Button text="+" class="font-weight-bold" tap="{{ $parents['ListView'].onPlusTap, $parents['ListView'].onPlusTap }}"></Button>
                <Label class="h3" text="{{ count }}"></Label>
                <Button text="-" class="font-weight-bold" tap="{{ $parents['ListView'].onMinusTap, $parents['ListView'].onMinusTap }}"></Button>
            </FlexboxLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Every item in items is an Observable now, updating an attribute will update the UI element too.

Comment: Thanks Manoj, i should really use the view model, i always end up putting the pages view model aside and work only with the xml file and the page.js, but what you shown me is the way of doing it, regards

Answer (score 1):

To implement this, you need to use custom view model and [Data Binding](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding) instead of direct manipulation of Label text value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, would it be possible for you to give me an example? i´m asking this because i never used that way. Regards